# how can i convert this into go_route code in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod, gorouter

```
ref.watch(currentUserAccountProvider).when(
  data: (user) {
    if (user != null) {
      return const HomeView();
    }
    return const SignUpView();
  },
  error: (error, st) => ErrorPage(
    error: error.toString(),
  ),
  loading: () => const LoadingPage(),
);
```

how can I convert it or do  the same function with go_route package flutter

I tried to pass ref as parameter to read the value of the the provider and make redirection with the value but I can not find a way to read it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined the router, like

```
final _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => HomeView(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/signUpPage',
      builder: (context, state) => SignUpView(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

you can navigate with

```
context.go('yourPath')
```

so you can change your code

```
if (user != null) {
context.go('/');
}
context.go('/signUpPage');;
```